# Synchronized Cache Matrix

Tags: java, multithreading, caching, mutual-exclusion

Im working on a java project for school where you have to deal with a multithreaded program.
I need a class, shared between many threads that is basically a matrix of values that have to manage concurrent access, it looks something like:

```
public class CacheMatrix{
private MyType[][] cachedItems;

public CacheMatrix(int size){
    this.cachedItems = new MyType[size][size];
}
public MyType readItem(int x, int y){...}
public void storeItem(int x, int y, MyType item){...}
}
```

I was about to manage it using a matrix of ReentrantReadWriteLock, one for each item, but i realized that the matrix size is around 10^3 X 10^3 so i would have 1 million lock!

Do you think this is the way to go? (is it ok to create so many locks?)

Can you find a better way that preserve almost only the minimum mutual exclusion but uses less lock, considering that the number of threads that use this class is limited to a small number N (N range from 2 to 8)?

Thanks fro your support!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may consider implementing [lock striping](http://www.thinkingparallel.com/2007/07/31/10-ways-to-reduce-lock-contention-in-threaded-programs/) in order to reduce the number of locks and still maintain performance.

Basically, an internal array holding `mylockscount = min(concurrencylevel, size)`  locks is created.
Whenever an read/write operation occurs, you lock on e.g. `mylocks[somehashfunction(x, y) % mylockscount]`.

This way, the number of locks should only scale with the number of concurrent threads and not the size of the matrix.

Comment: this is not bad, so in your example a good value for "mylockscount" could be the number of threads?

Comment: @Michele: basicaly, yes - but let instead "concurrencylevel" be the (expected) number of threads, so you can initialize "mylockscount" to either "size" or the number of expected threads - whichever is smaller.

Comment: @Michele: ...and "somehashfunction" might be a simple "xor", if you do not want to overdo it... :-)

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to replace `MyType[][]` with `AtomicReference<MyType>[][]`; in this case `void storeItem` will become `boolean storeItem(int x, int y, MyType oldValue, MyType newValue)` that returns false if `oldValue` does not equal the value currently held at `[x][y]` (under the surface you'd be calling `AtomicReference#compareAndSet(oldValue, newValue)`).  This way you don't have any locks, you just need to implement retry logic in case `storeItem` returns false

If `MyType` is a primitive, e.g. `int`, then use the appropriate atomic primitive e.g. `AtomicInteger` instead of `AtomicReference`

Answer (score 0):

Whats's about just making the accessing methods synchronized?

```
public synchronized MyType readItems(...){...}
```

Answer (score 0):

Two possible scenarios come to mind:

1) Use a single lock.  It's a bit naive, but it might solve your problem.

2) Lock only the ROWS or COLUMNS.  If you intend to access the matrix one item at a time on a random basis, this should do nicely, I think:

```
public class CacheMatrix
{
    private MyType[][] cachedItems;

    public CacheMatrix(int size) {
        this.cachedItems = new MyType[size][size];
    }

    public MyType readItem(int x, int y) {
        synchronized (cachedItems[x]) {
            return cachedItems[x][y];
        }
    }

    public void storeItem(int x, int y, MyType item) {
        synchronized (cachedItems[x]) {
            this.cachedItems[x][y] = item;
        }
    }
}
```